# Error: invalid_scope trying to auth google api via service acc

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, jwt

I need to read google sheets data using Service Account. Making auth manually since node.js lib is deprecated. I've made everything according to [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) guide.
Getting following responce:

```
  error: 'invalid_scope',
  error_description: 'Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.'
```

In the error description section for `invalid_scope` it says `No scopes were requested (empty list of scopes), or one of the requested scopes doesn't exist (i.e. is invalid)`.

1. Service account has owner role
2. I've copypasted the scope, it's correct 100%. Is there any additional scopes required?
3. Service account is impersonalised thus doesn't require app review
4. Document I'm trying to access is open, anyone can read it

I've checked some similar posts on SO, they're irrelevant to this particular service acc case (I've got regular auth with user consent, it works, but I need to do it automatically with SA).

Full auth function:

```
export async function authCustom(){
    try{
        const content = await fs.readFile(path.join(SETTINGS.APP_ROOT, 'data/CVT_ServiceAccKey.json'));
        const keys = JSON.parse(content);
        console.log(keys.private_key);
        var jwtClaim = {
            "iss":   "cv-thing-sacc@cv-thing.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
            "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly", // ok but not ok?
            "aud":   "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
            "exp":    Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60,
            "iat":    Date.now()
        };
        const token = jwt.sign({ jwtClaim }, keys.private_key, { algorithm: 'RS256' });
        console.log('SIGNED TOKEN:');
        console.log(token);
        const body = querystring.stringify({
                "grant_type":   "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
                "assertion":    token
            });
        var resp = await axios.post("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", body,
            {headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }}
        );
        console.log('AUTH RES:');
        console.log(resp.data);
        console.log(body);
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        Log(e, 'authResp');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In this case, `exp` and `now` are required to be seconds.
- In the case of `jwt.sign({ jwtClaim }, keys.private_key,`, the 1st argument is `{jwtClaim: {,,,}}`. In this case, please modify it to `jwt.sign(jwtClaim, keys.private_key,`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
var jwtClaim = {
    "iss":   "cv-thing-sacc@cv-thing.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly", // ok but not ok?
    "aud":   "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "exp":    Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60,
    "iat":    Date.now()
};
const token = jwt.sign({ jwtClaim }, keys.private_key, { algorithm: 'RS256' });
```

#### To:

```
const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
var jwtClaim = {
  iss: "cv-thing-sacc@cv-thing.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
  aud: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  exp: now + 3600,
  iat: now,
};
const token = jwt.sign(jwtClaim, keys.private_key, { algorithm: "RS256" });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I know SO doesn't apperciate this, yet I had to confirm in some way that it works. :)

Comment: @Corvus Corax Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.